# How bind works internally in kernel space?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

Can anyone help me in tracing `bind()` system call in socket programming. I would like to know what happens when `bind()` is called, in kernel space. Like which are the structures it updates and what functions are invoked in lower level

Comment: Don't trace. Look at sources.

Comment: You may like having a look into [Understanding Linux Network Internals by Christian Benvenuti](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002558.do).

Answer (score 1):

The `bind(2)` system call just configures the local side's address parameters that a socket will use once you have connected (or `sendto(2)`).  If you don't use it, the kernel selects defaults for it, depending on the underlying protocol.

The exact procedure `bind(2)` follows depends on the protocol family you are working on, as bind will behave differently depending if you are using `PF_UNIX`, `PF_INET`, `PF_PACKET`, `PF_XNS`, etc.

For example, in Unix sockets, you'll get your socket associated to an inode in the filesystem (an inode that supports unix sockets, of course), so clients have a path to connect to (in Unix sockets, addresses are paths in the filesystem).  In TCP/IP sockets, you can fix the local IP address or the local IP port your socket can listen on (to accept connections) or you can force a IP address and/or port to connect from, to a server.

For a deeper understanding of networking sockets internals, I recommend you reading the excellent book from W.R. Stevens *"TCP/IP Illustrated Vol 2. The implementation,"* describing the implementation of BSD sockets in NET2.  It's old, but still the best explanation ever made.  For a good introduction of the BSD socket system calls use, there's also an excellent book (for a long time it was indeed also the best system call reference for BSD unix system calls) by W.R.Stevens: *"UNIX network programming, Vol 1 (2ND Ed): The sockets API."*  Both are two jewels everyone should have available at work.